# Time of Apache and time of MySQL asynchronous

Tags: mysql, apache, asynchronous, time

I had a problem with displaying time in my website, and I checked with this code:

```
In php: echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
Result: 2015-10-09 09:40:54


In MySQL: SELECT NOW()
Result: 2015-10-09 05:40:54
```

I want to know my server has problem or I wrong with this code?

Comment: There is no problem. First one is UTC and the 2nd one uses the server's time zone.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's time() function returns the UTC time, so disregards time zone information, while mysql's now() function returns the local time within the configured time zone.

[strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function in PHP will return the local time in the configured timezone.